# UIImageView cropping

Tags: swift, uiimageview, crop

I am trying to allow users to crop an image. The problem is the cropped image is not the same as the view. Here are two screenshots to show what I mean.

pre crop screen:

!http://i58.tinypic.com/4rap9u.png

after crop

!http://i58.tinypic.com/2nrpjlj.png

Here is the code I use to create the new cropped image. The UIImageView is inside a UIScrollView to allow user to zoom and pan. Even when the image has not been zoomed it does not work correctly. Ideally I would like to allow the user to move the dashed square around the screen to select a portion of the image to crop, as well as zoom in/out.

```
func croppedImage() -> UIImage?
{
    var drawRect: CGRect = CGRectZero
    var cropRect : CGRect!

    cropRect = photoFrameView?.frame

    zoom = imgScroll.zoomScale
    println(zoom)

        drawRect.size = imgPreview.bounds.size
        drawRect.origin.x = round(-cropRect.origin.x * zoom)
        drawRect.origin.y = round(-cropRect.origin.y * zoom)
        cropRect.size.width = round(cropRect.size.width*zoom)
        cropRect.size.height = round(cropRect.size.height*zoom)
        cropRect.origin.x = round(cropRect.origin.x)
        cropRect.origin.y = round(cropRect.origin.y)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropRect.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

        self.imgPreview.image?.drawInRect(drawRect)

        var result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return result
}
```

here is where I crop the image:

```
    let cImg = croppedImage()!
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(cImg, nil, nil, nil);

    imgPreview.image = cImg
    self.imgPreview.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

Also here is the code for my UIView subclass(photoFrameView). Not sure if it is needed.

```
import UIKit

class mycropView: UIView {

var lastLocation:CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    // Initialization code
    var panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:"detectPan:")
    self.gestureRecognizers = [panRecognizer]

    self.addDashedBorder()
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func detectPan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    var translation  = recognizer.translationInView(self.superview!)

    self.center = CGPointMake(lastLocation.x + translation.x, lastLocation.y + translation.y)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    // Promote the touched view
    self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)

    // Remember original location
    lastLocation = self.center
}

override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent e: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

    if let result = super.hitTest(point, withEvent:e) {
        println("hit inside")
        return result
    } else {
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    return nil
}

}

extension UIView {
func addDashedBorder() {
    let color = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor

    let shapeLayer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let frameSize = self.frame.size
    let shapeRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)

    shapeLayer.bounds = shapeRect
    shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2, y: frameSize.height/2)
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = color
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [6,3]
    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shapeRect, cornerRadius: 5).CGPath

    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

}
}
```

Comment: Use CGImageCreateWithImageInRect

Comment: @k6sandeep I tried that it still is not correctly working. I am thinking it might have to do with that fact that `imgPreview.contentMode` is set to `.ScaleAspectFit` I just don't know how to calculate for it.